# Continually hide different elements depending on classes of another set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of menu elements `<a>` and a set of `div` elements (each containing to a django template. Currently have logic that switches an "active" class between the *menu* elements depending on which is clicked (highlighting that clicked menu item). Would like to have it so that only the django template corresponding to the "active" menu item is visible at any time. The existing code looks like this (it currently only changes which menu item has the "active" class):

```
<!-- top menu color activation -->
    <script>
        menu = {};

        // ready event
        menu.ready = function() {

          // selector cache
          var
            $menuItem = $('.menu a.item, .menu .item, .menu .link.item'),
            // alias
            handler = {
              activate: function() {
                $(this)
                .addClass('active')
                .closest('.ui.menu')
                .find('.item')
                .not($(this))
                .removeClass('active');
              }
            }
          ;

          $menuItem
            .on('click', handler.activate)
          ;

        };


        // attach ready event
        $(document).ready(menu.ready);

    </script>

    <!-- top menu (note, using semantic UI) -->
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui large secondary red pointing menu">
            <a class="toc item">
                <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="active item">item-1</a>
            <a class="item">item-2</a>
            <a class="item">item-3</a>

            <div class="right menu item">
                <div class="ui simple dropdown">
                    More
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div class="ui menu">
                        <a class="item"><i class="globe icon"></i> Choose Language</a>
                        <a class="item"><i class="settings icon"></i> Log Out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- including corresponding django templates (currently all visible) -->
    <!-- would like only item-1.html to be visible when menu item 1 is active and similarly for the other templates here -->
    <div>{% include "testapp/item-1.html" %}</div>
    <div>{% include "testapp/item-2.html" %}</div>
    <div>{% include "testapp/item-3.html" %}</div>
```

What I am not able to figure out is how to hide which django template is currently visible at any given time corresponding to the currently active menu item (eg. user clicks the item-1 menu item, then only the item-1.html django template should be visible).

How can I get this bit of functionality using jQuery? Very new to `JS` for front-end web page stuff and would appreciate any longer explanation of anything not obvious in the wording of the code.

Comment: What is your actual problem?. If the code works and you wish a review of it, you should post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have updated the question to hopefully reflect better what exactly I am trying to do and what the problem is (ie. yes, the existing code in the example works, but that snippet is only doing half of what I would like to implement (the other half I do not know how to do)).

Comment: I edited my answer. You should have all you need with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote your code in a shorter and more readable way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var item = $('.menu .item');
  item.on("click",function(){
    item.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

The code above does the exact same thing as your code.

---

**Edit**
Now to show a particular `div` based on that menu click, you should add a class to your "templates" and a data attribute, which is readable using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Click handler.
  var item = $('.menu .item');
  item.on("click",function(){

    // Add the active class.
    item.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // Show the right Django template.
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if(id!="" && typeof(id)!="undefined"){
      $(".template").hide();
      $(".template[data-id='"+id+"']").show();
    }
  }); // End click.

  // On load, only show the first template
  $(".template").hide();
  $(".template[data-id='1']").show();

}); // end ready.
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
.template{
  width:20em;;
  height: 8em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 3em #fff;
  margin:1em;
}
.template:nth-child(3){
  background-color:#6AA;
}
.template:nth-child(4){
  background-color:#A6A;
}
.template:nth-child(5){
  background-color:#AA4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui large secondary red pointing menu">
    <a class="toc item">
      <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="active item" data-id="1">item-1</a>
    <a class="item" data-id="2">item-2</a>
    <a class="item" data-id="3">item-3</a>

    <div class="right menu item">
      <div class="ui simple dropdown">
        More
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="ui menu">
          <a class="item"><i class="globe icon"></i> Choose Language</a>
          <a class="item"><i class="settings icon"></i> Log Out</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="template" data-id="1">item-1.html</div>
<div class="template" data-id="2">item-2.html</div>
<div class="template" data-id="3">item-3.html</div>
```